# How can i get number of quarters between two dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have MS SQL function `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, '2018-09-05')
```

that returns 474(integer).

What is PostgreSQL equivalent of this function ?

Comment: @Larnu, he's right to ask there's no datediff quarter in the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSSQL `0` is the date `'1900-01-01'` in `DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, '2018-09-05')`, that function will get the number of `QUARTER` from `1900-01-01` to `2018-09-05`

But PostgreSQL does not have a `QUARTER` number function.

You can try to use

1. `EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-09-05')` to get this month `QUARTER` number.
2. `date_part('year',age('2018-09-05','1900-01-01'))` get year number between 
   `'2018-09-05'` and `'1900-01-01'`.

then do some calculation.

```
select (EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-09-05') + 
      date_part('year',age('2018-09-05','1900-01-01')) * 4) -1 QUARTER
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/20755/0)**:

```
| quarter |
|---------|
|     474 |
```

Comment: This solution assumes the second date always stays in 1st quarter and two dates has more then a year gap while the question does not specify those requirements. Consider 01-Jul-2018 and 05-Sep-2018, using the solution yield the answer of 2, which is incorrect.

Comment: Please refer to Tim Yeung answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the current accepted is incorrect.

e.g. if you change date '1900-01-01' to '2017-07-01' you actually get **6** quarter diff.

- But expected result should be:

  - include first and last quarter: 5
  - exclude first and last quarter: 3
  - exclude last quarter: 4

```
    select 
        age('2018-09-05','2017-07-01') age,
        (EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-09-05') + 
      date_part('year',age('2018-09-05','2017-07-01')) * 4) -1 QUARTER
```

Result:

```
age                 |quarter|
--------------------|-------|
1 year 2 mons 4 days|      6|
```

The reason is `age('2018-09-05','2017-07-01')` return `1 year 2 mons 4 days` (maybe more than 12 month).

---

The answer i use to calculate number of quarter:

```
with params as (
    select 
        '2017-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp date_from,
        '2018-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp date_to
)
select      
    extract( quarter from date_from)::int date_from_quarter,
    (extract( quarter from date_to))::int date_to_quarter,
    age(date_to, date_from) date_diff,
    (extract(year from date_to) - extract(year from date_from))::int how_many_yr,
    -- exclude begin and end
    (extract(year from date_to) - extract(year from date_from))::int* 4 - extract( quarter from date_from)::int + (extract( quarter from date_to))::int - 1 quarter_diff,
    -- exclude begin quarter 
    (extract(year from date_to) - extract(year from date_from))::int* 4 - extract( quarter from date_from)::int + (extract( quarter from date_to))::int quarter_diff_include_current_quarter
    from params
;
```

Result:

```
date_from_quarter|date_to_quarter|date_diff           |how_many_yr|quarter_diff|quarter_diff_include_current_quarter|
-----------------|---------------|--------------------|-----------|------------|------------------------------------|
                3|              3|1 year 2 mons 4 days|          1|           3|                                   4|
```

Answer (score 0):

Its complicated on Postgres:

```
( (DATE_PART('year',  '2018-09-05') - DATE_PART('year', '1900-01-01')) * 12 
   + (DATE_PART('month',  '2018-09-05') - DATE_PART('month', '1900-01-01'))
) / 4
```

Additional resources: [topic](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two dates in the example table: start_date and end_date

Here is how to get the difference between these dates in number of quarters:

```
select * (year(end_date)*4 + quarter(end_date)) - (year(start_date)*4 + quarter(start_date)) as quarter_diff 
from example
```